# AvalonEdit scroll to line

Tags: c#, scroll, avalonedit

I am having a lot of trouble getting an AvalonEdit `TextEditor` to scroll to a specific line. The `ScrollTo()` behavior is simply to scroll until that line is in the middle of the view. I have tried many different methods found around the internet and SO like getting the offset with

```
double visualTop = textEditor.TextArea.TextView.GetVisualTopByDocumentLine(line);
```

But each has had its own issues. For example, in the above line I was getting exceptions with the `TextView.VisualLines`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that, since my text was all uniform height, I could just do line height * line# to get the offset. I first tried to do this using `(Editor.TextArea.TextView.DocumentHeight / Editor.Document.LineCount)`to calculate the line height but that seemed to be slightly off, probably due to some floating point issues, and was increasingly off the mark the farther you went down in the document. But, again since my document is uniform height, I realized I could use the `TextView.DefaultLineHeight` property and came up with:

```
double vertOffset = (Editor.TextArea.TextView.DefaultLineHeight) * Line;
Editor.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vertOffset);
```

This very consistently scrolls to exactly the right place in the document.

Comment: That works for me, but I have to subtract 1 from the line number. Also, I think it's a better user experience to set the caret offset to the line you've scrolled to.

Comment: It definitely depends on your application, but I like the caret idea. In my case though, I had two editors I wanted somewhat synced (sort of to create floating headers with data in a text file) so the window I was auto-scrolling was read only and no caret needed.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this is to set the caret position and then call BringCaretToView(). In F#:

```
editor.TextArea.Caret.Offset <- offset
editor.TextArea.Caret.BringCaretToView()
```

This will scroll the line containing 'offset' into view, but it won't scroll the text in the editor such that this line is now the first visible one. So which approach you take may depend on whether you want the target line to be at the top or not.

Comment: I needed to do this without moving the Caret. Also I found that methods like this sometimes didn't have the line I wanted at the top of the screen but just "in view" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in order to vertically center the desired line:

```
  var lineHeight  = editor.TextArea.TextView.DefaultLineHeight;
  var visualLines = editor.TextArea.TextView.VisualLines.Count;
  var vertOffset  = lineHeight * (DESIRED_LINE - (visualLines/2));

  editor.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vertOffset);
```